# Php Fopen Files

Tags: php

Hello Guys i want to ask about a php script that should Open the file normally it's downloaded to my application automatically to a file named " \home\exactarget\offers\suppression " but sometimes some problems happens within the Automatic Donwload so i have to download the file and upload to a that Folder what i doesn't know is How that File Must be , this is hwo the file is when it's been auto-downloaded ( sp5-10-2182-MD5.txt ) so thsi Code IS where the app must read what is in that file it's Called Check Suppression 
Thank You very much  !

```
<?php
    Include('../Includes/bdd.php');
    $requete = $bdd->query('select id_offer,suppressionFile_Offer,TypeSuppressionFile_Offer from offer');
    while($row = $requete->fetch())
    {
         $idOffer         = $row['id_offer'];
         $suppressionFile = $row['suppressionFile_Offer'];
         $typeSuppression = $row['TypeSuppressionFile_Offer'];

         if($typeSuppression =='text')
         {
                $subRequete = $bdd->query('select id_Email , email_Email from email');
                while($subRow = $subRequete->fetch())
                {
                    $file    = fopen('Suppression/'.$suppressionFile,'a+');
                    $idEmail = $subRow['id_Email'];
                    $email   = $subRow['email_Email'];
                    while($emailSuppression = fgets($file))
                    {
                        if(trim($email) == trim($emailSuppression))
                        {
                           $requeteSuppression = $bdd->prepare('insert into unsuboffer values(?,?)');
                           $requeteSuppression->execute(array($idEmail,$idOffer));
                           echo $email.'<br/>';
                           break;
                        }
                    }
                    fclose($file);
                }

         }
         else
         {
            $subRequete = $bdd->query('select id_Email , md5(email_Email) from email');
                while($subRow = $subRequete->fetch())
                {
                    $file    = fopen('Suppression/'.$suppressionFile,'a+');
                    $idEmail = $subRow['id_Email'];
                    $email   = $subRow[1];
                    while($emailSuppression = fgets($file))
                    {
                        if(trim($email) == trim($emailSuppression))
                        {
                           $requeteSuppression = $bdd->prepare('insert into unsuboffer values(?,?)');
                           $requeteSuppression->execute(array($idEmail,$idOffer));
                           echo $email.'<br/>';
                           break;
                        }
                    }
                    fclose($file);
                }
         }
    }
?>
```

Comment: "sometimes some problems happens". What problems are you experiencing?

Comment: Well the problem is when the API Key Doesn't work thsi API Key Allow me to Donwload the file automatically from web-site that Host those Supression Files as Optizmo.Com so when there is a problem with that Key i should do the Work Manually the thing that i don't Know how :/

Comment: but it only fails sometimes? How often? Is there a pattern? What error message do you get? Sorry, your description of the issue is a bit vague.

Comment: sorry for the descrption but that's what i have on that code, when i bought app it had 2ways to add supression file the first one is automatically and the second one is manually , sometimes the API Key Doesn't work and Sometimes some Network doesn't have any Api KEY so you are obligated to work in a manual way so you can forget about the Automatic Way since there is no API in a lot of Networks as i said the problem is where and How the Supression.txt should be Donwloaded and what title must have if you didn't really understood pass me Your Skype so i can show you screens and gives you phpfiles

Comment: but none of the code here deals with API keys, so I don't understand what you'd like fixing. We can only fix what's in front of us. You ask how the file should be downloaded...how can anyone know that? You've said nothing about it except it should go into a certain folder and sometimes it doesn't. As for  title or contents, again how should anyone know? You've given no details about it. It sounds like this isn't your app, and you have no idea what it's doing. Does the code above work or not? If it does, why have you posted it? Post something relevant. Your question is unanswerable right now.